# ASP.net Global Cache?

Tags: .net-3.5

Is there a way in ASP.net to cache something to memory say x="foo", such that any session can access that cache?  Due to contraints, I have to use memory and can't store this in a database or file system.  It's fairly volatile and does not need to hang around for a long time.

Comment: and what's wrong with HttpRuntime.Cache? I mean, have you considered using it?

Comment: Make it an answer and give an example then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this piece of code to store on the Cache some data for 30 minutes (absolute expiration)

```
Cache.Insert("CacheItemKey", "CachedItemValue",  null, 
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),   System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

On [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) MSDN article you have a lot of information about how to use the Cache object

If you're not using a web farm or a web garden the cache object object is global for ALL your web sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the [HttpContext.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx) would work well for that.  Alternatively, I've never used it but [HttpContext.ApplicationInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.applicationinstance.aspx) won't get cleared out by the system (Cache will occasionally be cleaned outside of your control).